# How can I know if I'm banned from answering without trying to answer?

Tags: support, answers, post-ban

I gave some bad answers on Stack Overflow and as a result I'm banned from answering again.

I know that to lift up the ban, I need to gain reputation by asking questions and eventually the ban will be removed.

But how do I know my ban was removed without trying to actually answer questions?

What happened several times already, that I spent some time on writing an answer to later discover I'm banned.

Comment: I think hiding that info until you try to post something helps them prevent people from guessing what the algorithms are for avoiding bans.

Comment: Have you considered seeing if you could fix your existing answers?

Comment: I deleted the bad answers I gave.

Comment: @AlexWeitz IIRC, deleted answers count against you. The recommendation is to edit them into good answers and undelete

Comment: Thank you for the advice, unfortunately I can no longer see the answers I deleted, but I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: You can use `deleted:1` in the search query to find your own deleted answers.

Comment: @Jester - Don't you still need enough rep to see deleted posts?

Comment: I think you can see your own without problem, it's not the question that has been deleted.

Comment: @Jester Using `user:660921 deleted:1` gives me *all* my answers, and just `deleted:1` gives me all answers on the site. It looks like you need 10k rep for this :-/

Comment: Yeah, looks like it. See [relevant meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted).

Comment: Good luck digging your answers out of a ditch... I'm told that works really, really well.

Comment: When I first came to Stack Overflow I didn't know how to ask and answer questions well so my account got banned. Rather than waiting however long it takes to get unbanned, I just started over with a new account.

Comment: @Suragch I too like to live on the edge, but being as badass as you is my dream :D

Comment: @Suragch nowadays system limits those who deleted account and restarted to [one question per week](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230899/165773) - "f you're _blocked_ at the time you remove your account and return, you'll be limited to one question per week until you can establish yourself as a contributor to the site..."

Comment: @gnat, he meant that he started a new account. Not deleted his original account.

Comment: It seems like some of you guys upvoted my question and answers, thank you for that @Carpetsmoker silly question, but how can I know my user?

Comment: It's in the URL of your userpage: `http://stackoverflow.com/users/3501205/alex-weitz` So it's `3501205`.

Comment: Hmm, this seems counter productive. It is hardly going to encourage the crafting of quality answers if it isn't clear that the system is going to allow the user to post it.

Comment: I agree that the current implementation of the ban-checker sucks. They should make answer bans just like question bans. When you're banned, there should be an error message in place of the text box.

Comment: Undelete this question => https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349852/4356188

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There seems to be no way to know until you try.

There is [an excellent explanation of this at MSE by Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252645/165773). It was written by a former Stack Exchange Community Manager to explain question bans, but the general reasoning appears to apply to answers as well:

> ...ban is applied when a user who qualifies for it tries to ask a question. Until that point, they're like [that cat in a box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat), both banned and unbanned.
>
> […]
>
> As usual, I'm not going to publish the *actual* formula, but I'll make a few notes as to the nature of these bans:
>
> - There are multiple, cooperating algorithms at work. Some of them result in permanent bans, others just apply stricter rate-limits […]

Comment: How do you know the formula? I heard that only moderators and the people working on SO know the formulas?

Comment: @AshishAhuja moderators don't know the formula either. If you happen to click the link to the post I quote (["excellent explanation..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252645/165773)) you'll find out that its author is Stack Exchange employee, Community Manager - _he_ knows the formula