# Is there any tag I can post a question to for testing?

Tags: support

My average question rep is now at -1.4

Yes, I have some ..umm.. 'less than optimal' questions, but I have also accumulated a fair few 'pairs and triples' - downvotes applied at the same time so as not to be regarded as serials by the script.  Strangely, these seem to appear after outing deadbeats, homework vamps and other abusers.

Anyway, I've not really bothered much with the bad question average because I hardly ever ask questions, but what if I do need to ask?  How can I tell if I'm question-banned now without actually asking a pointless question?

If there is no specific 'test' tag, I guess I could find a quiet tag and post some dup and, if successful, immediately delete it?

Comment: Related, for answers: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318202/how-can-i-know-if-im-banned-from-answering-without-trying-to-answer

Comment: '.ban is applied when a user who qualifies for it tries to ask a question. Until that point, they're like that cat in a box, both banned and unbanned... Doan' wanna be no HeisenUser!

Comment: Maybe it would help you to *not* "out deadbeats, homework vamps and other abusers" in your own, fairly recognizable, way ...

Comment: Would using the "contact us" link to ask about whether you're banned be appropriate?

Comment: There is an old adage that says: If you're house is made of glass,you shouldn't throw stones at people :)

Comment: +1 for what @RadLexus said. Going through your comments, you often come across as rude and whiny. If you don't have anything productive to say, it's better to just keep quiet.

Comment: @Stijn: I kinda liked [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068845/segmentation-fault-in-following-code#comment61684539_37068845), though.

Comment: @Stijn sure, then it's 'why no comments on downvotes, down and close votes for no reason, hostile, mob downvoters'

Comment: @ryanyuyu I didn't want to make any more work for mods than they already have.

Comment: @Sukl nitpick: "If you're house" > "If you are house"!? "If your house" is possessive.

Comment: Related: [Where does it tell you the status of a ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322554/where-does-it-tell-you-the-status-of-a-ban)

Comment: As long as you don't get any down votes or answers, you can delete a question without it counting towards a ban.