# I was banned, unbanned, then a asked a good question, banned, then 5 seconds later unbanned?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

Edit: I have just been unbanned again.

I am very confused. I was banned. Then after receiving serial upvotes, which got reversed, I was unbanned. I asked a good question (+1) and now I am banned.

Why did SO ban me after I asked a good question? The serial upvotes were reversed before I asked my last question.

What happened?

Comment: The term "ban" might be a little misleading. From what we know about the system, your eligibility to ask questions is decided whenever you click the "ask a question" button.

Comment: "...ban is applied when a user who qualifies for it tries to ask a question. Until that point, they're like that [that cat in a box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat), both banned and unbanned..." ([How can I know if I'm banned from answering without trying to answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318204/839601))

Comment: The original question has been answered. You can't keep editing it as your edits make the answer make less sense than it originally did. As the answer said you're teetering on the edge so all you can do is improve your existing questions and answers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just an odd timing of events. The upvotes had been reversed, but the post scores hadn't been recalculated yet, so they were still counting towards your account until last night when they got fixed. The reversal script runs at 03:00 UTC, but the script which fixes all post scores in the database runs at 00:00 UTC - so you have to wait for 21 hours after a reversal for the scores to actually fix themselves, unless someone does it manually.

But it also didn't take much to get you unblocked again. As you can see, you're kind of teetering on the edge of the block at the moment. Some more good questions will get you farther away from the block so you won't have to worry about that.