# How to tell the date you got question/answer/edit/review banned?

Tags: discussion

I recently got a question ban (I couldn't ask questions), but the last time I asked one was about two weeks ago, so I would like to know the exact date I got banned. I tried emailing Stack Overflow, but they haven't replied for two days.

**Note: I am trying to figure out when I got banned, not how I can get out of it. I have read many articles and have a basic idea of how to do that.**

Comment: You don't get banned at a specific date. Whenever you try to post the system weighs all the contributions you have and then if it's above a certain (secret) threshold, you can post. When you're banned, 6 months after your last post, you can post one time to try and get a contribution high enough to get you out of the ban

Comment: Again, there is no 'date' for you to get banned. Unless you count the moment your contributions slipped under the ban threshold. But since said threshold is secret, that specific instant won't be given. The only time that matters is that 6 months after your last post, since you'll be allowed to post.

Comment: oh, ok. I want to ask another question: I recently got 10 reputation (after the ban) for an upvoted answer will that count towards getting me out of the **question** ban

Comment: You sure you read the dupe you say you read? Because that info is in there. Basically yes it might help, but very minimally. Edit your questions to get upvotes on them, that's the way you'll get out of this

Comment: My downvoted questions were my early ones and some of them were just a stupid mistake so it is inevitable that they were downvoted. There will be no reason to upvote them without changing the essential point of the post.

Comment: Then you might be able to get them disassociated from your account by flagging for moderator attention (MIGHT, I don't know what weighs in the decision to disassociated). But all your 0 questions don't help. You could get upvotes on this if you edit them into shape maybe?

Comment: The questions asks, "how to tell the date", and not "what to if you are banned". **Not dupe.**

Comment: @peterh I believe the duplicate answers the question "How long do I have to wait before I can post again?"

Comment: @HereticMonkey Probably this is what the OP wants to know, but not this is what he asks. Imho we should answer what he asks.

Comment: I'm positive one can survive and profit from the site without asking a single question

Comment: ["There seems to be no way to know until you try..."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318204/839601)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According @Patrice's excellent [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371725/how-to-tell-the-date-you-got-question-answer-edit-review-banned#comment615138_371725), the date you want to know is the last question or answer you could yet post. Then starts the 6 months.

However, I've heard there are multiple ban times, depending on, how deep is your question record. It is not sure that you've got 6 months, it is also possible that you've survived with just 2 weeks. I don't know more details, but you might hunt for more infos here on the meta, in the chat or on the https://meta.stackexchange.com .